# Test Cases Selection for Automation

Tags: automation, manual

I am from Manual Team and I got an responsibility to analyze the Scenario which we have to automate.Can Anyone help me to get the Exact Criteria/Cases/Templates from that I can identify the Test Cases For Automation.

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13611/steps-for-identifying-test-cases-to-automate